# Does Golden Meta Cooler have ki?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-heroes

So in Dragon Ball Heroes meta Cooler appeared and he turned into Golden Meta Cooler. Supposedly meta Cooler is an android, but a yellow aura surrounds him when he transforms in Golden Meta Cooler.

Does Golden Meta Cooler have ki?

Answer (score 1):

**Golden Meta-Cooler is not fully an Android.**

Within Dragon Ball Heroes' non-canonical events, Cooler became a cyborg through Fu's manipulations and modifications. Fu used the **[Cosmic Suit](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmic_Suit)** to convert Cooler into Meta-Cooler. A Cosmic Suit was previously used by Frieza after being defeated by Goku ; this form is commonly known as "Mecha-Frieza" within the fandom.

Cosmic Suits are built by mechanizing **[Bio Suits,](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Bio_Suit)** biological pieces of clothing and armor that are naturally grown by Frieza's species over time. In essence, although Cosmic Suits do mechanize their wearer to some extent, they do not transform their holder into true cyborgs, which explains why Golden Meta-Cooler can release ki. By comparison, Metal Coolers from the non-canonical movie *"Dragon Ball Z: The Return of Cooler"* were built by the Big Gete Star, and were fully mechanical, explaining the absence of ki.

It should be emphasized that Dragon Ball Heroes is entirely non-canonical and mainly serves as an advertising product for the Dragon Ball Heroes game. Disparities and inconsistencies should probably be accepted as such, for the anime doesn't really aim for complete accuracy.